# To-do list - HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, to-do-list

I created my first "program": a to-do list. I would appreciate it if somebody could look at the code and give me some hints on how to improve it.

```js
var list = document.createElement("ol");
list.id = "list";
list.className = "list";
  
var addTask = document.getElementById("inputBtn");
addTask.addEventListener('click', function (){
   
 // checking whether the field is empty
 var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
 if(task=="") alert("Are you sure you do not have any task to do?");
 else
 {
  // adding an element
  addElement (list, task);
  
  //clear the input field
  document.getElementById("task").value ="";
 }
}, false);
 
function addElement(ol, text)
{
 var element = document.createElement("li");
 element.id = "element";
 element.className = "element";
 element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
 ol.appendChild(element);
 document.getElementById("board").appendChild(ol);
 
 //adding a remove button
 addRemoveBtn(element);
 
 //adding a function which change the decoration of the text
 addCrossStyle(element);
}

function addRemoveBtn(li)
{
 //creating a remove button
 var removeTask = document.createElement("input");
 removeTask.setAttribute("type", "button");
 removeTask.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
 removeTask.setAttribute("class", "remove"); 
 
 //remove task function
 removeTask.addEventListener('click', function (){
  li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
 }, false);
 li.appendChild(removeTask);
}
  
function addCrossStyle(li)
{
 var check = false;
  
  li.addEventListener('click', function (){
   if (check==false)
   {
     li.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
     li.style.textDecorationColor = "red";
     check = true;
   }
   else
   {
     li.style.textDecoration = "none";
     check = false;
   }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #26282E;
 color: #b3b3ff;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
}

h1
{
 font-size: 64px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

.addtask
{
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

input
 {
   margin-top: 10px;
   border: solid;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #b3b3ff;
}

input::placeholder 
{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

.inputBtn
{
 background-color: #8080ff;
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 3px black solid;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 font-size: 28px;
}

.inputBtn:hover
{
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color: #6b6b99;
}

.list
{
 width: 900px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #b3b3ff;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: white;
}

.remove
{
 background-color: #b30000;
 border: 3px black solid;
 color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
 font-size: 12px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-right: 5px;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
}
.remove:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: red;
}

.element
{
 position: relative;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 font-size: 22px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom: solid #8080ff;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.element:hover
{
 background: #8080ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>To Do List</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Szymon Wolny">
 
 <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">

</head>

<body>
 <header>
  
  <h1> To Do List</h1>
 </header>
 
 <main>
 
  <article>
   
   <div class="addtask">
    <form>

     <input type ="text" name="task" placeholder="New task..." id="task" size="45" ><br>

    </form>
    <button type="button" id="inputBtn" class="inputBtn">Add a new task to the List </button>
   </div>
   
   <div id="board"></div>
   
  </article>
 
 </main>
 
 <script src="todo.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

so just 2 things here:

1. `if(task=="") alert("Are you sure you do not have any task to do?");`
   such comparison is a bit risky in JS. In case of checking for empty values it's better to do `if(!condition) {} else {}` or at least `if(task ==="")` (strong type checking). Not saying it's wrong in this case, just a rule of a thumb. Read more about issues with JS comparison / type casting, you'll find out what I mean.
2. Creating UI in code is fine of course, and it's nice to understand what's going on under the hood, but for *readability* of your UI you mind find it better to define everything up-front in HTML and than later just show / hide parts of it or add remove classes, depending on your application state. This is not a general guideline, because it only makes sense for small-medium apps, for larger, more complex, you probably will use some framework anyway (angular or such).
   Other than that, fine simple app (assuming it works, didn't run it to be honest) ;).